# Split an array of q promises into packets and run these packets in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

My goal is to copy files and limiting the files copied in parallel to a defined variable. Therefore I split up an array of `q` promises with calls to `fs.copy` into packets and run these packets in series using the reduce function.

```
var promise = _.reduce(packets, function (previous, packet) {
    var map = _.map(packet, function (file) {
        return q.nfcall(fs.copy, file.source, file.target);
    });
    return previous.then(q.all.bind(null, map));
}, q());
```

*How can I achieve my goal with `q`?*

Comment: If you had an array of promises, the tasks would already have been started.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What does not work?

Comment: @Bergi When I monitor the target directory, I notice, that my program started more copy tasks, than I configured. It seems, almost all tasks started the same time. Of course I have not an array of promises; I create the promise chain the way I described.

Comment: Oh right, how could I miss that. Writing an answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems, almost all tasks started the same time.

Yes, and that is because both `map` and `reduce` are synchronous, iterating over all packets and creating all tasks immediately.

Instead, you need to put the `q.nfcall(fs.copy, …)` invocations in the `previous.then` callback (which you've <s>obscured</s> hidden quite elegantly with `.bind()`), so that they will only be called after `previous` resolves:

```
var promise = _.reduce(packets, function (previous, packet) {
    return previous.then(function(packetresult) {
        var map = _.map(packet, function (file) {
            return q.nfcall(fs.copy, file.source, file.target);
        });
        return q.all(map); // optionally, also pass the previous packetresult
    });
}, q([]));
```